# Auto width when add list

Tags: css

I have a simple menu (centered with `margin:0 auto`) with some list items.
 Now, I'm trying to keep the menu on the same centered position when I add an additional list items.
Here is the fiddle [**play with it**](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/LXGDt/1/)

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 56%;
  max-width:600px

 }

ul li{

display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;

}
```

I want to an additional `li`'s to the `ul` to wrap it and still be centered.

I don't want to use flexbox because IE doesn't support it :D

```
The problem is solved. Giving the ul {display:table} Thank you all,especially Coop !
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. When you say "when i add an additional list" is it a `li` element or `ul` ? What is the result when you add one ?

Comment: In your example, do you want the `li` items (100px in width) to be evenly spaced within the `ul` block or do you want the `ul` block to shrink to fit the `li` items?

Comment: One of the potential issues here is that when you add a fourth item, the list wraps into a second line...

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jn42h/ If you add li elements they'll space evenly

Comment: I want when i add more li the ul to wrap it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're after but I've often had issues centering nav menus and came up with this solution:

```
ul{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red; }

ul li {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000; }
```

Note the li's are floated so you also need to clear them on the ul. I'd suggest a clearfix solution to do that. For example the full code could be:

```
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red; }

ul li {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000; }

.clear:before, .clear:after { content: " "; display: table; line-height: 0; }
.clear:after { clear: both; }
.clear { *zoom: 1; }
```

...

```
<ul class="clear">
  <li>First item here</li>
  <li>Second item here</li>
  <li>Third item here</li>
</ul>
```